# Get postal code from full address column in dataframe by regex str.extract() and add as new column in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, postal-code

I have a dataframe with full addresses in a column, and I need to create a separate column with just the postal code of 5 digits starting by 7 in the same dataframe. Some of the addresses may be empty or postal code not found.

How do I split the column to just get the postal code?
the postal code start with 7 for example 76000 is the postal code in index 0

```
MedicalCenters["Postcode"][0]
Location(75, Avenida Corregidora, Centro, Delegación Centro Histórico, Santiago de Querétaro, Municipio de Querétaro, Querétaro, 76000, México, (20.5955795, -100.39274225, 0.0))
```

Example Data

```
    Venue         Venue Latitude Venue Longitude Venue Category Address
0 Lab. Corregidora  20.595621   -100.392677      Medical Center Location(75, Avenida Corregidora, Centro, Delegación Centro Histórico, Santiago de Querétaro, Municipio de Querétaro, Querétaro, 76000, México, (20.5955795, -100.39274225, 0.0))
```

I tried using regex but I get and error

```
# get zipcode from full address
import re 
MedicalCenters['Postcode'] = MedicalCenters['Address'].str.extract(r'\b\d{5}\b', expand=False)
```

ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-84c21a29d484> in <module>
      1 # get zipcode from full address
      2 import re
----> 3 MedicalCenters['Postcode'] = MedicalCenters['Address'].str.extract(r'\b\d{5}\b', expand=False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1950                 )
   1951                 raise TypeError(msg)
-> 1952             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1953 
   1954         wrapper.__name__ = func_name

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in extract(self, pat, flags, expand)
   3037     @forbid_nonstring_types(["bytes"])
   3038     def extract(self, pat, flags=0, expand=True):
-> 3039         return str_extract(self, pat, flags=flags, expand=expand)
   3040 
   3041     @copy(str_extractall)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in str_extract(arr, pat, flags, expand)
   1010         return _str_extract_frame(arr._orig, pat, flags=flags)
   1011     else:
-> 1012         result, name = _str_extract_noexpand(arr._parent, pat, flags=flags)
   1013         return arr._wrap_result(result, name=name, expand=expand)
   1014 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in _str_extract_noexpand(arr, pat, flags)
    871 
    872     regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
--> 873     groups_or_na = _groups_or_na_fun(regex)
    874 
    875     if regex.groups == 1:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in _groups_or_na_fun(regex)
    835     """Used in both extract_noexpand and extract_frame"""
    836     if regex.groups == 0:
--> 837         raise ValueError("pattern contains no capture groups")
    838     empty_row = [np.nan] * regex.groups
    839 

ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups

time: 39.5 ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to get make it a group

```
MedicalCenters['Address'].str.extract(r"\b(\d{5})\b")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split the string first, then it will be easier to match the postcode:

```
address = '75, Avenida Corregidora, Centro, Delegación Centro Histórico, Santiago de Querétaro, Municipio de Querétaro, Querétaro, 76000, México, (20.5955795, -100.39274225, 0.0'

matches = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('7') and len(x) == 5, address.split(', '))) # ['76000']
```

So you can populate your DataFrame by:

```
df['postcode'] = df['address'].apply(lambda address: list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('7') and len(x) == 5, address.split(', ')))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Data of Address were an object thats why the regex was not working

```
MedicalCenters.dtypes
Venue               object
Venue Latitude     float64
Venue Longitude    float64
Venue Category      object
Health System       object
geom                object
Address             object
Postcode            object
dtype: object
time: 6.41 ms
```

after convert object to string :

```
MedicalCenters['Address'] = MedicalCenters['Address'].astype('str')
```

I was able to apply the regex modified thanks to glam

```
# get zipcode from full address
import re 
MedicalCenters['Postcode'] = MedicalCenters['Address'].str.extract(r"\b(\d{5})\b")
```

[image: OUTPUT]